# What is the runtime of the inner loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, search, runtime

I made a function that loops through the array and prints any two values of the array that can add up to a value K. The outer for loop is O(n), but the inner loop is a bit confusing to me if the runtime is a O(Log n) or O(n). can you help please? Thank you!!

```
int canMakeSum(int *array, int n, int key){
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = (i+1); j < n; j++){
      if(array[i]+array[j] == key){
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", array[i], array[j], key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The inner loop runs (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n*(n-1)/2 times. Adds up to a total of O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already shown, the inner loop is still **O(n)**; it's a mean of n/2 iterations, the values 1 through n distributed evenly over the iterations of the outer loop.

Yes, you can solve the problem in **O(n log n)**.

First, sort the array; this is `n log n`.  Now, you have a linear (**O(n)**) process to find all combinations.

```
lo = 0
hi = n-1

while lo < hi {
   sum = array[lo] + array[hi]
   if sum == k {
       print "Success", array[lo], array[hi]
       lo += 1
       hi -= 1
   }
   else if sum < k        // need to increase total
       lo += 1
   else                   // need to decrease total
       hi -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As the inner loops is dependent to the value of the outer loop, you can't find the complexity of the total porgram without analyzing the both with together. The complexity of the inner loop is `n - i - 1`.

If you want to compute the complexity of the program, you can sum over `n - i -1` from `i = 0` to `i = n - 1`.  Hence, the total complexity is `T(n) = (n - 1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 + 0 = (n-1)n/2 = \Theta(n^2)` (as the statment in the inner loop has a constant complexity (`\Theta(1)`)).

Comment: Got it!! Thank you. Is there anyway to enhance the algorithm of the whole function and make it O(n) or O(n log n)?

Answer (score 0):

Although the inner loop decreases in the number of items it scans for each iteration in the outer loop, it would still be O(n). The overall time complexity is O(n^2).

Imagine you've an array of 25000 elements. At the starting point at `i = 0` and `j = 1`, the number of elements that j will iterate through (worst case no matches to key) is 24999 elements. Which is a small difference from the total number of elements, so it is 'like' going through n elements.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you. Is there anyway to enhance the algorithm of the whole function and make it O(n) or O(n log n)?